# Gradually transitioning FSM

Tags: automata, fsm, pushdown-automaton

It is given that a particular object can have two states at any point in time and that the object transitions from one state to another gradually.

I am modeling the state-graph to capture all the possible states the object can have and their corresponding transitions.

Now, for the modeling of the execution of such a graph, pedantically modeling using an [FSM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) means that an object should be in one and only one state. With a dual-state object as described above, I want to understand if there exists something similar (in academia) to FSM that talks about handling such a use-case.

Comment: You speak of gradually transitioning. What does this mean? Does it mean that the machine exists in a superposition aX + bY of states X and Y, where a and b are coefficients? If so, are there a finite number of pairs (a, b) (with a+b=1, e.g.) or infinitely many? If the former then, yes, the FSM model is enough to handle this; otherwise, the model cannot be handled in that formalism and I am not really aware of one that easily maps to it. If the coefficients are rational numbers then clearly the system can be simulated using TMs; if they are arbitrary reals, not even TMs can simulate.

Comment: It is the former with finite set for coefficients. Thanks for your response, it helped.